# Random point $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed in the unit square.

Tags: probability-theory

0

Random point $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed in the unit square. At which values for the constant "c" the events ${|X - Y| \geq c}$ and ${X+Y \leq 3c}$ are independent?

I found that p.d.f. of $(X+Y)$ as: $f_{(X+Y)}(X+Y)=(X+Y)$ when $0<(X+Y) \leq 1$ and $f_{(X+Y)}(X+Y)=1-(X+Y)$ when $1<(X+Y) \leq 2$.
 Also found that p.d.f. of (X-Y) as: $f_{(X-Y)}(X-Y)=1+(X-Y)$ when $-1<(X-Y) \leq 0$ and $f_{(X-Y)}(X-Y)=1-(X-Y)$ when $0<(X-Y) \leq 1$.

I think that to find when the events are independent I need to find when $Pr\{|X - Y| \geq c,X+Y \leq 3c\}=Pr\{|X - Y| \geq c\}*Pr\{X+Y \leq 3c\}$ but I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: Draw unit square and find all the probabilities as the area of the corresponding parts of the square.

Comment: Thanks you. If the two events don't overlap inside the unit square would that be enough to say that they are independent?

Comment: These are always dependent.

Comment: @Math-fun They definitely aren't dependent if $c\geq \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @GeorgiD If events don't overlap and have positive probabilities, they are dependent.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou consider for example $c=1/2$ (satisfying your claim). Then consider an little ball centered at $x=-0.75$ and $y=0.5$ with radius $0.1$ ... this is included in both sets. For every other value for $c$ you can always find such a ball easily ...

Comment: @Math-fun: The ball you're suggesting is a null-set under the uniform distribution on the unit square. My point is that $1_{X+Y\leq 3c}$ is $1$ a.s. for $c\geq 2/3$ and hence, is independent of everything. You are right, though, that I gave the wrong constant.

Comment: So if $X+Y\leq 3c$ happens for $c\geq 2/3$, the other set must also happen ...

Comment: What do you mean? Say $c=2/3$, then $(1,1)$  satisfies $x+y\leq 3 c$ but not $|x-y|\geq 2/3$ - this is again true in a neighbourhood of the point. The point is that a degenerate variable is independent of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region $X+Y\le3c$ is the region below the downward sloping line. The region $|X-Y|\ge c$ is the region outside the parallel lines. So for $c\le\frac{1}{3}$ we have the situation in the first image. The shaded regions show the overlap.

As $c$ increases, the parallel lines move further apart and the downward sloping line moves up.

So for $\frac{1}{3}<c<\frac{1}{2}$ we have the situation in the second image, and for $c>\frac{1}{2}$ we have the situation in the third image. Note that for $c>\frac{2}{3}$ the downward sloping line has moved out of the square, so the whole square satisfies the inequality $X+Y\le 3c$.

[[image: <span class=]$c\le\frac{1}{3}$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPx9k.png)
[image]
[image]

The condition for independence of events $A,B$ is $p(A\text{ and }B)=p(A)p(B)$. So we have to calculate those three probabilities. Let us call $|X-Y|\ge c$ event $A$, and $X+Y\le3c$ event $B$. The area outside the parallel lines is just the area of a square side $1-c$, so $p(A)=(1-c)^2$. For $c<\frac{1}{3}$ the area below the downward sloping line is $\frac{1}{2}(3c)^2$. For $\frac{1}{3}\le c\le\frac{2}{3}$ it is $1-\frac{1}{2}(2-3c)^2=6c-\frac{9}{2}c^2-1$. For $c>\frac{2}{3}$ it is 1. So we have $p(B)$. If we plot the product $p(A)p(B)$ we get:

[image]

We now calculate the area of the overlap region. For $c\le\frac{1}{3}$ it is two halves of a square diagonal $2c$. So the area is $2c^2$. For $\frac{1}{3}<c<\frac{1}{2}$ it is a square side $1-c$ less a square diagonal $2-4c$, giving an area of $(1-c)^2-\frac{1}{2}(2-4c)^2=6c-7c^2-1$. For $c>\frac{1}{2}$ it is two halves of a square side $1-c$, so area $(1-c)^2$. So we have $p(A\text{ and }B)$. If we plot $p(A)p(B)$ and $p(A\text{ and }B)$ together we get:

[image]

So we guess they are equal for $c=\frac{1}{3}$ and $c\ge\frac{2}{3}$. Checking we find that indeed $p(A)p(B)=p(A\text{ and }B)=\frac{2}{9}$ for $c=\frac{1}{3}$.

For $\frac{1}{3}<c<\frac{1}{2}$ some tiresome algebra shows there are indeed no solutions. For $\frac{1}{2}<c<\frac{2}{3}$ we have $$p(A)p(B)=(1-c)^2(6c-\frac{9}{2}c^2-1)\ne(1-c)^2=p(A\text{ and }B)$$ For $c>\frac{2}{3}$ we have $p(B)=1$ and so $p(A)p(B)=p(A\text{ and }B)$.

So the values of $c$ giving independence are $c=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}\le c<1$. Note that we are told that $X,Y$ are points in the unit square, so we must have $0\le c\le1$. If $c<0$ then $X+Y\le3c$ is impossible for both $X,Y\ge0$; and if $c>1$, then $|X-Y|\ge c$ is impossible. Alternatively, note that if $p(A)=0$ or $p(B)=0$, then $p(A\text{ and }B)=0$ also, and so $A,B$ are independent (albeit trivially).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation

Comment: You forgot $c\leq 0$.

Comment: @NCh Thanks. Fixed.